# Regarding the use of tf.train.shuffle_batch() to create batches

Tags: tensorflow

In [Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#shuffle_batch), it gives the following example regarding `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`:

```
# Creates batches of 32 images and 32 labels.
image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
     [single_image, single_label],
     batch_size=32,
     num_threads=4,
     capacity=50000,
     min_after_dequeue=10000)
```

I am not very clear about the meaning of `capacity` and `min_after_dequeue`. In this example, it is set as `50000` and `10000` respectively. What is the logic for this kind of setup, or what does that mean. If input has 200 images and 200 labels, what will happen?

Comment: Hi mrry, do you have any suggestions for this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

The [`tf.train.shuffle_batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch) function uses a [`tf.RandomShuffleQueue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RandomShuffleQueue) internally to accumulate batches of `batch_size` elements, which are sampled uniformly at random from the elements currently in the queue.

Many training algorithms, such as the stochastic gradient descent–based algorithms that TensorFlow uses to optimize neural networks, rely on sampling records uniformly at random from the entire training set. However, it is not always practical to load the entire training set in memory (in order to sample from it), so `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` offers a compromise: it fills an internal buffer with between `min_after_dequeue` and `capacity` elements, and samples uniformly at random from that buffer. For many training processes, this improves the accuracy of the model and provides adequate randomization.

The `min_after_dequeue` and `capacity` arguments have an indirect effect on training performance. Setting a large `min_after_dequeue` value will delay the start of training, because TensorFlow has to process at least that many elements before training can start. The `capacity` is an upper bound on the amount of memory that the input pipeline will consume: setting this too large may cause the training process to run out of memory (and possibly start swapping, which will impair the training throughput).

If the dataset has only 200 images, it would be easily possible to load the entire dataset in memory. `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` would be quite inefficient, because it enqueue each image and label multiple times in the `tf.RandomShuffleQueue`. In this case, you may find it more efficient to do the following instead, using [`tf.train.slice_input_producer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/slice_input_producer) and [`tf.train.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch):

```
random_image, random_label = tf.train.slice_input_producer([all_images, all_labels],
                                                           shuffle=True)

image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([random_image, random_label],
                                          batch_size=32)
```